# Advanced Use of Kibana DSL filter

Tags: elasticsearch, search, filter, kibana

I'm looking for data in Kibana web console's filter.

but my data format as follows.

```
{ "myField" : "A3|C5|D6|E4" }
```

What should I do if I want to select 5 corresponding to C in myField?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: could you please clarify your goal? what do you want to search for and what would you like to get back?

Answer (score 0):

Although @glenacota is correct, You need to be more specific about the question here, but assuming a few things over here.

1. { "myField" : "A3|C5|D6|E4" } will contain all the value in a similar kind of pattern all the time.
2. By selecting the value "5" corresponding to C, you meant storing it in another variable.

Then the below solution is for you.

You need to add below grok pattern in the filter part of your logstash config:

```
filter {
grok {
     match => {"myfield" => "A%{NUMBER:A}\|C%{NUMBER:C}\|D%{NUMBER:D}\|E%{NUMBER:E}" 
     } 
    }
   }
```

This will store all the values 3,5,6, and 4 in separated variables A, C, D, and E respectively.